# How to switch from Grub to rEFInd without breaking everything

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, grub, refind

Okay so a little backstory:
I've been trying to install Linux as a dual boot (with Windows) since yesterday, here's how it went down :

- installed Debian, worked well but I had to boot in `nomodeset` for some reason and it hardblocked me in 4:3 resolution
- a friend told me Debian was a weird distro choice so I mehed and tried to install MX instead : I still had the nomodeset problem, but it also killed my grub (weird normal error preventing grub from launching)
- since the distro had the same problem, I tried with a third one (EndeavourOS) which (yay) didn't have the nomodeset problem.

However, the Grub was still broken, so impossible to launch on-disk.

I tried fixing the Grub for a few hours, gave up and decided to instead switch to rEFInd. I installed it with pacman, ran the refind-install (got an warning saying I wasn't in EFI mod, which was normal I guess since I was working from my USB boot) and I also had to rename a file to match my AMD gear.

BUT when I restarted, I still fell on the grub error page. So I relaunched from the USB, removed Grub with pacman, and deleted everything with "grub" in the name on my EFI partition (there was a grub folder I wiped from /boot/, and also some `grubx64` files in /efi/).

I thought that would force switch to rEFInd but instead it just broke the launch totally, and now the only option I have in the BIOS is Windows.

I'm still rather new with Linux so please detail your solution a little. What I know how to do is :

- Launch Endeavour from my USB and mount the installed one there
- Use pacman to install packages
- basic file management

---

EDIT:

Just completely wiped my hard drive and reinstalled Windows then Linux. I still get the exact same grub error :

```
error: verification requested but nobody cares: (hd0, gpt5) /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod
```

Comment: You have to be consistent in how you boot, both from live installer & once installed. And since hardware since 2012 is UEFI, you probably should always be booting in UEFI mode. The rEFInd boot manager is for UEFI systems. If you needed nomodeset, you probably have nVidia, and had not installed the correct nVidia driver. With Ubuntu's latest versions, you can choose Safe Boot to include nVidia & install restricted drivers to have installer install nVidia driver. No need for nomodeset &  will have correct video modes. In UEFI boot menu you should have two boot options, one clearly UEFI.

Comment: I don't want to use Ubuntu since I have really bad experience with their update software. Also, I have an all-AMD desktop, so the nomodeset stuff was surely not related to Nvidia.

Comment: Did you reinstall both systems in UEFI boot mode? And with AMD, you should not need nomodeset, but must have some video configuration issue with those distributions. Issue is typical of booting an old grub from other boot mode. Or you have UEFI install, but booting in BIOS mode or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you are booting using UEFI and a GPT drive you can install what ever OS you want or any boot loader you want when you want as long as you have an ***esp*** partion(mine is 100MB but I saw recommendations for up to 500MB) ahead of time.

If you don't want to handle with partioning your drive ahead of time you can install first the Windows, that will create an esp partion for you.

Now, set in the bios settings or how ever you set  your boot order of the UEFI, to boot from rEFInd.

If you want to boot directly to linux without grub and it doesn't recognize your partition then it might be the same problem I answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1508402/883131).

There are 2 simple ways to install rEFInd:
***Manual:***
Copy into /boot/efi/EFI/refind the content of the [binary zip file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.14.0.2/refind-bin-0.14.0.2.zip/download) content after extract. In the refind dir you will see a file named *refind_x64.efi*.
***Less Manual:***
Download and put on a usb drive the image from the [USB Flash drive image file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.14.0.2/refind-flashdrive-0.14.0.2.zip/download) in the download section. Boot from the usb drive and you will see an option to install rEFInd. Done. Reboot and everything should just work.
***also less manual:***
If your distro has a package that installs rEFInd you can use it and hope for good :)
I use Void Linux, as it doesn't use systemd which in my opinion is better for personal use as there is no systemd which makes it easier for newbies from my own experience, so the command will be `xi refind`.